# whats the problem with my balancing brackets solution?

Tags: c, stack

```
char *isBalanced(char *s) {
    int flag = 0;
    int u = strlen(s);
    char arr[1001];
    int top = -1;
    printf(" u %d", u);
    for (int i = 0; i < u; i++) {
        printf("i = %d %c\t", i, s[i]);
        if (s[i] == '}' || s[i] == ']' || s[i] == ')') {
            if (arr[top] == s[i]) {
                // arr[top] = ' ' ;
                top -= 1;
                flag--;
                printf("flag-- flag %d top %d \n", flag, top);
            }
        }
        if (s[i] == '{' || s[i] == '[' || s[i] == '(') {
            arr[++top] = s[i];
            flag++;
            printf("flag++ flag %d top %d \n", flag, top);
        }
    }
    printf("%d %d", flag, top);
    if (top == -1) {
        return "YES";
    } else {
        return "NO";
    }
}
```

I was solving a balancing brackets stacks problem. I noticed something weird about my program the closing bracket if statement is not working. I want to know why?
also I think my logic is right. I don't know why that if statement is not working!

Comment: What is the input you are testing?  What happens when you step through the code in a debugger?

Comment: its hackerrank function which i have completed https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/balanced-brackets/problem you can look at this here.

Answer (score 1):

#### Mishandling the string `"}"`

The string `"}"` will cause you to do an out of bounds lookup at the following line because `top == -1`.

```c
          if(arr[top] == s[i]){
```

#### Mishandling the string `"[)]"`

The string `"[]]"` will not cause an out of bounds lookup, but you won't actually complain about the extra close paren.